# Use virtual host certificate

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, windows-10, sni

I'm trying to enable SSL in name-based virtual hosts. From docs I understand that SNI does not need to be enabled explicitly, it happens automatically if both server and client comply with minimum requirements, with I think they do:

- Apache/2.4.25 (Win32)
- OpenSSL/1.0.2k
- Firefox/51.0.1 (x64)

I've stripped configuration to the bare minimum:

```
Listen 80

LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "D:/Servidores/Apache/htdocs"
</VirtualHost>


Listen 443
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4
SSLProxyCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv3
SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv3
SSLPassPhraseDialog builtin
SSLSessionCacheTimeout 300

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "D:/Servidores/Apache/htdocs"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "D:/DOS/Apache24/conf/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "D:/DOS/Apache24/conf/server.key"
</VirtualHost>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName tmp
    DocumentRoot "D:/tmp"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName tmp
    DocumentRoot "D:/tmp"
    SSLCertificateFile "D:/Servidores/Apache/certificados/tmp.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "D:/Servidores/Apache/certificados/tmp.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

```
C:\>httpd -f conf/prueba-test.conf
```

Yet when I attempt to load `https://tmp/` I always get the certificate from `<VirtualHost _default_:443>` (for host `localhost`) rather than the certificate for `ServerName tmp` (for host `tmp`).

This is what gets logged:

```
[Fri Mar 03 14:11:57.360237 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 11684:tid 668] AH01906: tmp:80:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Mar 03 14:11:57.361240 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 11684:tid 668] AH01906: localhost:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Mar 03 14:11:57.433220 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 11684:tid 668] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Fri Mar 03 14:11:57.433220 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 11684:tid 668] AH01906: tmp:80:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Mar 03 14:11:57.434223 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 11684:tid 668] AH01906: localhost:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Mar 03 14:11:57.436228 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11684:tid 668] AH00455: Apache/2.4.25 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2k configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 03 14:11:57.436228 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11684:tid 668] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Dec 17 2016 10:42:52
[Fri Mar 03 14:11:57.436228 2017] [core:notice] [pid 11684:tid 668] AH00094: Command line: 'httpd -d D:/DOS/Apache24 -f conf/prueba-ssl.conf'
[Fri Mar 03 14:11:57.444250 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11684:tid 668] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 15380
[Fri Mar 03 14:11:57.910024 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 15380:tid 648] AH01906: localhost:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Mar 03 14:11:57.988164 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 15380:tid 648] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Fri Mar 03 14:11:57.988164 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 15380:tid 648] AH01906: localhost:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Mar 03 14:11:57.988164 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 15380:tid 648] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

What can the problem be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it was nothing but a silly mistake. I was missing this in my secondary virtual host:

```
SSLEngine on
```

Since this is the [directive that enables SSL](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslengine), I didn't have SSL at all (neither SNI, nor regular) in such host.

*(The directive has been there for years in all my IP-based virtual hosts but when I started playing with SNI I someone managed to remove it in the host I was testing.)*

Answer (score 0):

It may have to do with the order in which they are configured.
Try moving the `<VirtualHost _default_:443>` configuration to the bottom of the file and reload/restart apache.

Comment: That should prevent `localhost` from being the default host any more, shouldn't it? However, it makes some difference: now I get `SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG`, as if it's finally reading my `tmp` configuration (and finds it isn't correct). I'm researching on that error right now.

Comment: I think `SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG` means that it isn't using SSL at all. If I load `http://tmp:443/` site loads (kinda, because it triggers `AH00025: configuration error:  couldn't check user: /`).